# Create Course API not working in Moodle

Tags: php, web-services, api, post, moodle

I am new to Moodle. I have done creating user by using web service api and that is running successfully. Now I want to create a course same way. I am using 'core_course_create_courses' function to do this. The post body of my request is

```
$courses=array("courses" =>
            array(
                0=>array(
                    "fullname" => $fullname,
                    "shortname" => $shortname,
                    "categoryid" => $categoryid,
                    "idnumber" =>$idnumber,
                    "summary"=>$summary,
                    "summaryformat"=>$summaryformat
                )
            )
        );
```

Whenever I am running this it is giving me response "**{\"exception\":\"moodle_exception\",\"errorcode\":\"errorcatcontextnotvalid\",\"message\":\"You cannot execute functions in the category context (category id:101). The context error message was: Invalid parameter value detected\"}"**.

But the course category 'programming' with id 101 exists in my moodle site. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong ,the categoryid is not the id of the category,it is the sequence id of the category.Now if I give 2 ,it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
$token = $this->config->item('id_token');
    $domainname = $this->config->item('domainname');
    $functionname = 'core_course_create_courses';
    $restformat = 'json';

    //crear objeto de acuerdo a la estructura para crear Categoría en Moodle

    $curso = new stdClass();        
    $curso->fullname = $data['patron']['nombre']; 
    $curso->shortname = $data['patron']['nombre']; // Is unique
    **$curso->idnumber = $id; // consecutive
    $curso->visible = 1;
    $curso->categoryid = 6; 

    $modulos = array($curso);

    $params = array('courses' => $modulos);

    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $serverurl = $domainname . '/webservice/rest/server.php' . '?wstoken=' . $token . '&wsfunction=' . $functionname;
    require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/curl.php');
    $curl = new curl;

    $restformat = ($restformat == 'json') ? '&moodlewsrestformat=' . $restformat : '';
    $resp = $curl->post($serverurl . $restformat, $params);
    return $resp;
```